# Inheritance and templates in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have the following problem with inheritance and templates:

```
class Base {};
class Deriv : public Base {};

template <class T> class X{};

void f(X<Base>& inst) {}

int main()
{
  X<Base> xb;
  f(xb);
  X<Deriv> xd;
  f(xd);
  return 0;
}
```

The program doesn't compile because there is not relation between `X<Base>` and `X<Deriv>`. Nevertheless I think it should be possible to do everything that can be done with `X<Base>` also with `X<Deriv>`. Is there anything that I could do other than copying the function body of `f` to a new function `void g(X<Deriv>& inst)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think they should be related? Consider the following:

```
template<typename T>
class X;

template<>
class X<Base> {
    int x;
};

template<>
class X<Deriv> {
    double d;
};
```

They're definitely not interchangeable. So no, there is no relation between those classes and you can't pass one to a function expecting the other. You'll have to do something like make both types inherit from another common type that exposes the interface you need.

---

Regarding your comment, you can use type traits and `static_assert` to do what you would do in Java:

```
template<typename T>
void f(X<T>& inst) {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of(Base, T)::value, "Template type must subclass Base");

    // body of function...
}
```

Comment: Well, in this case there is nothing in `X<Deriv>` that is not also in `X<Base>`, the only difference between the two is the difference between `Deriv` and `Base`

Comment: @hfhc2 yes there is, `x` is in `X<Base>` and not in `X<Deriv>`, and `d` is not in `X<Base>` but it is in `X<Deriv>`. The difference is more than just the type parameter.

Comment: Well, that is not what I mean to do. In my program I am using a boost graph which has the type `adjacency_list <vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS, VertexProperties, EdgeProperties>`where the properties are classes holding some parameters. In one function however, I need a graph with different properties which are however derived classes of the original properties. Otherwise the graph class does not change and I see no reason why this should not work.

Comment: @hfhc2 that's just how C++'s type system works. A different class is a different class, period. You can think of `X<Deriv>` and `X<Base>` as being like `A` and `B`. They're not related in any way, and using templates with different types creates _completely different and incompatible classes_. They are as different as if you did `class A { }; class B { };`

Comment: It occurs to me that in Java I would write the function based on generics, enforcing that the template parameter is a class that extends `Base` `X<? extends Base>`. Is it possible to achieve this effect using C++?

Comment: @hfhc2 yes, see my update. But you don't really need that `? extends Base` thing in C++, because the compiler will error if the type does not support the interface you are using in the function.

Comment: Well, I will just write a template-based function, but I have to say that this is handled a lot cleaner in java. Thank you, though.

Comment: @hfhc2 why do you want to add that restriction at all? Either it compiles and works, and you have more flexibility by letting the user not have to derive types from `Base`, or it will give you a compile-time error. It's a win-win situation when you don't enforce it being a subclass of `Base`. If you do it that way, C++ handles it cleaner than Java because you don't need _any_ kind of enforcement.

Answer (score 2):

You could just continue using templates:

```
template<class T>
void f(X<T>& inst) {}
```

will work for both `X<Base>` and `X<Derived>`.

The compiler *might* duplicate the code (if it is not smart enough), but you don't have to.

Comment: The compiler *will* duplicate the code. If the function is inlined, by means of the inlining, if it is not, it has to generate the two instantiations (the addresses of the specializations must differ)

Comment: If nobody is looking (not comparing addresses) the compiler can cheat. Anyway, the main point is that the OP doesn't have create several functions, the compiler can do it for him.

Answer (score 0):

If you need such functionality, then you must template on the type- or overload, as you have said. Alternatively, you might explicitly specialize `X` such that `X<Derived> : X<Base>`.

Comment: Could you show me how to change my code to specialize the class and get everything working?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Consider the case where `X` is `std::shared_ptr`. It would break type safety if `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` was derived from `std::shared_ptr<Base>`, but instead there is an implicit value conversion.

However, since you’re passing by reference to non-`const`, such a value conversion will not help you you directly.

Other possibilities include inheriting from a common interface, and templating your function.

Comment: Well, the interface is supposed to be `Base`, if I pass `X<Deriv>` to `f` I would like this to be treated as if it were an instance of `X<Base>`

Comment: @hfhc2: to quote myself, that "would break type safety". in general.

Answer (score 0):

Different instantiations of a template are unrelated types, even if the instantiating template arguments are related. That is, `X<A>` is not related to `X<B>` regardless of what the relationship between `A` and `B` might be.

Now as of what can be done, it depends on what your template actually is.  In some cases you can provide conversions so that the `X<Derived>` can be converted to a `X<Base>` for a particular operation. Another alternative is modifying your function to be able to take any `X<T>` for which `T` derives from `Base` (this can be done by creating a template and using SFINAE to disallow calling it with `T`s that don't derive from `Base`. Again, depending on what your template is, you might be able to offer access to the underlying type, in which case the function could take a reference to `Base` (consider `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` with the `.get()` method)

Without a description of what you actually want to get done it is impossible to provide a good alternative.